# Android Motion Layout - textAlignment custom attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-motionlayout

I'm using MotionLayout and using it to animate a TextView that has two lines of text, in the center of the screen. Then I'm animating it to move to the left edge of the screen, and I want at the same time that this animation occurs to change it's textAlignment from center to viewStart.

I tried setting the custom attribute inside the Constraints like this:

```
<Constraint
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textAlignment"
                motion:customIntegerValue="5" />
```

and inside the Transition block like this

```
<KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                motion:framePosition="0"
                motion:motionTarget="@id/message"
                motion:attributeName="textAlignment"
                motion:customIntegerValue="4" >
            </KeyAttribute>
            <KeyAttribute
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:motionTarget="@id/message"
                motion:attributeName="textAlignment"
                motion:customIntegerValue="5">
            </KeyAttribute>
        </KeyFrameSet>
```

But none of those tactics worked, and the text inside the TextView does not get left/start aligned and is always centered.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What you have actually kinda works, but changing just the text alignment is apparently not enough to invalidate the `TextView` and cause a redraw. There are ways to force it – e.g., resetting the text simultaneously, using `gravity` instead, etc. – but I have a feeling that it's not going to result in what you're expecting. It won't be a smooth transition from centered to start-aligned; it'll just jump from one to the other at some point. If you need the smooth transition, that might require a different setup; e.g., two `TextView`s, one for each line, or maybe some sort of custom `View`, etc.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had already tried to use gravity but it didn't work either. I thought about using two textviews, that seems to be the best workaround, but I will try force a redraw to see how it looks like.

Comment: OK, if you do decide to go that route, I think you're meant to use a `<KeyTrigger>` instead, which seems to be made for "one-shot" events whose values aren't gradually animated. In the setups you have now, the `textAlignment` value is actually being animated, but since it's an integer value in a very small range, you don't notice. (That might be why `gravity` didn't seem to work, since its individual values are all over the place.) Unfortunately, that requires some code setup, too, since trigger methods can't take arguments. Anyhoo, just FYI, from what I gathered from my quick tests last night

Comment: Here's the `<KeyTrigger>` setup from my test project, if it might be of use to ya: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dw6a--YVCfuDy3DgsqPFzJ37EcT4_Bff/view?usp=sharing. It's a simple setup with a custom `TextView` to drag between the start edge and center, flipping the text alignment halfway through. (That reminds me of the other reason why `gravity` might not have worked for you: if you set the `textAlignment` to anything other than the default value of `gravity`, changing the gravity won't affect the text alignment.)